# Nokogiri scrubs style and script tags in after/before

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to add a bunch of html to an existing nodeset, at the top. It mostly works, but the style tags and script tags are getting scrubbed of their content. Here's what I mean:

```
doc.xpath("//head/*[1]").before("<script>var xb=25</script>")
```

But if I try to display this, this is what I get:

```
hdoc.xpath("//head/*[1]")
=> <script></script>
```

It is scrubbing everything in between script and style tags, and ignores html comments altogether. Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: wow. I can't believe I didn't get an answer either on the mailing list or on stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 3):

Current Nokogiri master fixes this issue.